# WSServletContextListener in Spring Boot and Embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot sample applicaiton i am using embedded tomcat. Its a new application. I have created jax-ws webservice and using SUN's implementation. For that matter i've created sun-jaxws.xml and kept it in WEB-INF folder. Below is my configfiguration for the listerner

```
@Bean
public WSServletContextListener wsServletContextListener(){
    WSServletContextListener wsServletContextListener = new WSServletContextListener();
    return wsServletContextListener;
}
```

However, on server startup i get below error

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader$MetroConfigUrlLoader can not access a member of class org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext with modifiers "public"

Please suggest. My observation is that this works fine with external or standalone tomcat and gives problem for embedded tomcat. The packaging type for my application is war

Comment: Did anybody face above issue?

Comment: What is jaxws-tubes.xml ? Why is it getting referred instead of sun-jaxws.xml?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. The [JIRA bug raised](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-1175) should be upvoted to be fixed I suppose.

Comment: hi. I am looking for the same solution